# Hive maximum case when expressions (statement)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, case

Although Typically a Look-up table "should"(using loosely) be used for large case expressions to keep things simple and easy to maintain in case of errors. Does anyone know the maximum number of case when expressions for a hive sql query/statement or where there is a document or source code for it?

Note: I'm still reading up on the source code in my spare time but I ran into this issue with a view. Statement is used instead of expression in the title of the question to make it easier to find the answer to the question.

Edit: statement -> expression

Comment: I'm not aware that Hive supports a `case` *statement*.  It does support a `case` expression though.

Comment: Ahhh yes, it is an expression. Although there are far too many online resources including other stack overflow questions which make reference that it is a "statement". I will edit my initial question to reflect the correction.

Comment: . . It may seem like nit-picking, but some databases have both case *expressions* and case *statements*.  The latter are used in scripting languages.

Comment: No worries, I prefer "things" to be correct instead of the latter. A quick case expression test was used on my version of hive to verify whether it was an expression or statement. I was just verifying things lazily(trusting the internet) instead of eagerly which has its pros and cons - but the exact reason why asking questions and making a "fool" of myself can be a good thing - ie I don't have the leisure to know every feature of every language of every version inside and out as much as I try.

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences, a case statement in Hive can only include 128 when clauses at most.